# How to take a screenshot of lengthy website on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to capture the entire webpage(from the top navbar to the footer section at the bottom) on Chrome browser but I'm unable to because it only allows me to take screenshots of the viewport(my laptop's screen size).

So is there any way I can capture image from top to bottom of the webpage?

Comment: Google Chrome > Open DEV Tools > Click "Toogle Device Toolbar icon" or press Ctrl+Shift+M > Increase the height eg: 2000 > Click Vertical Menu Icon (three dots) right side towards the width / height tool bar > Capture full size screenshot

Answer (score 3):

1. In Google Chrome open the Developer Tools, one way is to right-click on the web page and "Inspect".
2. Open the "Device Toolbar" using the second icon on the tool bar in the Developer Tools.
3. Open use the 3-dot menu to find "Capture screenshot" and "Capture full size screenshot".

[image: Icon to toggle the Device Toolbar]

[image]

Comment: i dont want to take full screenshot. Actually my webpage is too long with many info. I just want to cover both of the images area shown above. i.e. i want something that i can take screenshot of the area even by scrolling web page.

Comment: @safinghoghabori Take a full screen shot and then crop it in an image editor. Or more painstakingly take two screen shots and merge them together in an image editor.

Comment: @safinghoghabori You could also try zooming out `ctrl+-` (control + minus/dash) and then take the screen shot; it will be smaller than actual size but it may work find for sharing.

Comment: @dyanjameswagner yes if i do in editor as you told then it will be possible but need some painstaking. and by using `ctrl+-` its decreasing quality and makes blur pic.

Answer (score 1):

Step to take a screenshot using Developer tools shortcuts

1. **Step 1:**
   if you are using window
   Press = **Ctrl + Shift + I**

   or if you're on a Mac

   Press = **Command + Option + I**
2. **Step 2:**
   if you are using window

   Press **Ctrl + Shift P**

   or if you're on a Mac

   Press = **Command + Shift P**
3. **Step 3:** Type "screenshot." Don't press Enter.

Comment: It's not what i want. i want something that i can take screenshot of the area even by scrolling web page. while in this tool we can only capture present screen.